# Как узнать, что вызвало событие onpause у видео - нажатие кнопки паузы или выход на домашний экран телефона?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="Numb.mp4" controls onpause="OnPause()"></video>
    <script>
      function OnPause() {}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит "сворачивание видео"?

Comment: Выход на домашний экран из браузера. Какую проверку нужно прописать в функцию OnPause(), чтобы видео продолжило воспроизводиться, если было прервано из-за выхода на домашний экран?

Answer (score 0):

Любой Event что приведёт к событию onpause, будет вызывать функцию OnPause.

Comment: Какую проверку нужно прописать в функцию OnPause(), чтобы видео продолжило воспроизводиться, если было прервано из-за выхода на домашний экран?